# The file names are not transliterated on upload

Tags: 7, files, transliteration

I am using Drupal 7 and have transliteration module enabled.

I have a file field and I want to have the names of the uploaded files to be transliterated on upload.

The url alias for the nodes are well transliterated. But the file names are not.

I checked the settings for file system. The current settings are:

- Transliterate file names during upload.(checked)
- Lowercase transliterated file names. (checked)

If I "Transliterate existing file names" (admin/config/media/file-system/transliteration) then the names of the files I have already uploaded are transliterated. But still, when I upload new files, the file names are not transliterated.

Any ideas why the names are not translated on upload?

Comment: The transliteration settings *should* be right off `admin/config/media/file-system/settings`

Comment: @Jimajamma, I cannot understand what you mean. What should be off?

Comment: if you go to `www.yoursite.com/admin/config/media/file-system/settings` the transliteration options should be right there

Comment: @Jimajamma yes, they are there and I have set them as stated in the question. Still the filenames are not transliterated.

Comment: You did not mention `Transliterate file names during upload` which is the key setting on the menu I mentioned.  If you installed transliteration AFTER you uploaded files, the files prior still may have oddball chars in them but all new file uploads should be transliterated.  If this is the case, there is a TRANSLITERATION button (by default up in the top right corner) that will allow you to bulk transliterate those preexisting files.  If this is not the case, then it suggests a installation issue on your site that is beyond the scope here.

Comment: @Jimajamma Actually I did mention to **Transliterate file names during upload**. I now updated the question. And I tried "Transliterate existing file names". It works fine. But still, when I upload new files, the file names are not transliterated

Comment: is this a file field ? did you check the settings on the field ?

Comment: @mojzis, it is a file field. I checked the settings of the field but found none related with transliteration. Which setting exactly are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

File names are not URL aliases. Pathauto has never had any sort of integration with files at all.

Comment: Right, thank you. I edited the question and hope it describes the problem better now.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, you could add debug in

[`transliteration_init`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21transliteration%21transliteration.module/function/transliteration_init/7)

To check the value of `$_FILES` and transliteration there.

for example, to test the var value, add

```
watchdog('debug', var_export($_FILES, 1));
```